# If statement in function issue

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I can't get the `if/else` statement in the `totalBalance` function to work correctly in this code and I'm not sure why.

I have tried switching the greater than to less than and seeing if it solves the outcome but it makes no difference.

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/mike43237/dfakmwas/)

```js
var moneyAmount = 0;
var food = 0;
var bills = 0;
var total = 0;

moneyAmount = prompt("how much money do you earn per month?");
amountCheck();

document.write("Your balance is " + "£" + moneyAmount + "<br>");

food = confirm("Do you have any food bills?");

if (food === true) {
  food = prompt("How much per week?")
  document.write("You spend £" + food + " on food per week <br>");
} else {
  alert("Lucky!")
};

totalBalance();

/* total = moneyAmount - food; */
console.log("money amount = " + moneyAmount);
console.log("food = " + food);
console.log("total = " + total);


function totalBalance() {
  total = moneyAmount - food;
  console.log("total is " + total);
  if (total > moneyAmount) {
    document.write("Your total amount of money per month is £" + total);
    console.log("nay");
  } else {
    document.write("You need to save more money £" + total);
    console.log("yay");
  };
}


function amountCheck() {
  while (isNaN(moneyAmount)) {
    alert("Please enter a numeric value");
    moneyAmount = prompt("how much money do you have to spend?");
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `prompt()`, which is really annoying, why not make a simple form and a "Submit" button that can do all the math?

Comment: What's not working about it?

Comment: I bet one of them is a string.

Comment: FYI: Your JSFiddle is trying to use isNaN() as a property of a string.... strings do not have a isNaN() function. Take a look at the console for error messages

Comment: I am a total beginner so all of this is valid, I'm not sure how to add js to dom elements yet and I used isNaN to make sure a number was entered into the first prompt. I didnt think that would effect another function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

total will never be more than moneyAmount, because total is moneyAmount - food. So `if (total > moneyAmount)` will never evaluate as true unless food is a negative value. Not sure what exactly you're going for, but simply changing the if statement to `if (total > 0)` makes more sense to me given the context.